# Scope return null when filter exact value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-blade

Code

```
$scope.banks = [
                {
                 id : 1, name : examples
                },
                {
                 id : 2, name : examples 2
                },
                .....
               ]

<ui-select ng-model="item.bank_id" theme="selective">
@{{bank_name}}
```

Expected result

```
{id : 2, name : examples 2},
```

Assume `item.bank_id` returned 2 from the `ng-model`

```
$scope.bank_name = $filter('filter')( $scope.banks, {id: $scope.item.bank_id});// Returned list of values that id contains 2 
$scope.bank_name = $filter('filter')( $scope.banks, {id: $scope.item.bank_id}, true);// Returned [] null
$scope.bank_name = $filter('filter')( $scope.banks, {id: 2}, true);//Returned expected result
```

I'm trying to get the exact result from the `$scope.banks` however, the `$scope.item.bank_id` returned `2` when I put a console log and I don't know why it returned `[]` null to me when added `true` in the filter. But, when hardcoded `2` it returned the expected result `

Answer (score 0):

3rd parameter in filter - comparator

Optional. Defines how strict the comparison should be. The value can be:

true : Returns a match only if the value of the array item is exactly what we compare it with.

false : Returns a match if the value of the array item contains what we compare it with. This comparison is not case sensitive. This is the default value.

So you added the 3rd optional parameter, true, to your 2nd filter test. That means the 2nd parameter object must match exactly to an object in your array. The object {id: $scope.item.bank_id} does not match an object in your array, hence returning empty results.